# Position indicator in HERE SDK premium is not showing

Tags: android, sdk, navigation

Here is my simple implementation.

The MapFragment is already initialized. If I do the simulation mode the position indicator is showing but if I switched to the actual TBT navigation it is not showing where I am located.

```
PositionManager positioningManager; 
    if(positioningManager == null) {
                        positioningManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
                        positioningManager.addListener(new WeakReference<>(positionChangedListener));
                        positioningManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);
                }

                positionIndicator = mMap.getPositionIndicator();
                positionIndicator.setVisible(true);
                positionIndicator.setAccuracyIndicatorVisible(true);

private PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener positionChangedListener =
            new PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositionUpdated(PositioningManager.LocationMethod locationMethod,
                                      GeoPosition geoPosition, boolean b) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPositionUpdated " + locationMethod.name());
            Log.d(TAG, "Coordinates " +geoPosition.getCoordinate());


    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionFixChanged(PositioningManager.LocationMethod locationMethod,
                                     PositioningManager.LocationStatus locationStatus) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPositionFixChanged " + locationMethod.name() + " status " + locationStatus.name());

    }
};
```

Comment: Does your TbT navigation module use a different MapFragment/Map? If so you would need to call `setVisible` on the new instance of `PositionIndicator`. Also, during TbT navigation do you continue to get positioning callbacks in the location you expect?

Comment: I am using the same MapFragment/Map for TbT navigation. For navigation the Position Indicator still not showing. 

What I did is upgrade  SDK 3.1 to 3.3 and that fix the problem.

Comment: Why are there v3.1 still floating around? That came from last September.