# Unable to get user's current position using Here maps sdk

Tags: android, gps, here-api, android-gps

I am trying to get the users current location with GPS.

Below is my initialize() method which gets called after getting all the required permissions. I am trying to get the geoposition of user with this line as specified on Here maps documentation 
`PositioningManager posManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();`
 `posManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS);`
`GeoPosition position = posManager.getPosition();` 
now my problem is position always returns `null`, not sure where am I going wrong.

initialize() method:

```
    private void initialize() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
        mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                    // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                    map = mapFragment.getMap();
                    // Set the map center coordinate to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                    map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(19.174598, 72.860722),
                            Map.Animation.NONE);
                    // Set the map zoom level to the average between min and max (no animation)
                    map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                    MapMarker marker = new MapMarker();
                    PositioningManager posManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
                    posManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);
                    posManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS);
//                    GeoPosition position = posManager.getPosition();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onEngineInitializationCompleted: " + posManager.hasValidPosition(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK));
                    TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
                    boolean temp = posManager.hasValidPosition(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);
                    info.setText(Boolean.toString(temp));
                    marker.setCoordinate(new GeoCoordinate(19.1745, 72.8));
                    map.addMapObject(marker);
                } else {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot initialize MapFragment (" + error + ")");
                }
            }
        });

        textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        textViewResult.setText(R.string.textview_routecoordinates_2waypoints);

    }
```

Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mapstutorial.simplerouting" >

    <!-- <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
        No longer needed since this is specified in build.gradle -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".RoutingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
            android:value="bm8G03BysQAjEHvyCgSm" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
            android:value="CprS7w8rXTBHblaSlb8xVQ" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the link to [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/jsjain007/c21c4a221602baa5a7b6f38dbb884062) with complete java code.  Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong.

This java code is just a slight modification of Here map's sdk example.

Comment: What kind of device are you testing with? Maybe it does not have a GPS antenna?

Comment: Letv 1s, android marshmallow.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833725/heremap-positioninglistener-was-never-called, you can see some debugging suggestions there.

Comment: as discussed there and you said `posManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);` returns true
 still  `posManager.hasValidPosition(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);` returns null. do I have to get the position for current location in `addListener` method only ??

Comment: is it because of the default `appid` and `apptoken` I am using from the sdk example ?

Comment: Did you apply for an appid / apptoken via developer.here.com? The permission key is tied to the application id, token and namespace of your application. If they do not match, the SDK will not function.

Comment: Did the code print:  Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot initialize MapFragment (" + error + ")");

Comment: map is initializing properly so it calculation of routes, only gps location is not  working, I even tried creating my own app and using my own `appid` and `apptoken` still the same, do I have to include something extra to get current location in build gradle ?

Comment: @DavidLeong yes I have created my own app in studio then making the project on here dev portal and using id and token with the same app name, routing is working fine only gps location is not woring

Comment: Thanks for the help @DavidLeong , I figured out the issue , since my building is multi-storied my phone was unable to get the gps signal I tried it outside of my building it worked.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewJC for your help as well

Comment: You can use the Android DDMS tools and inject a position to the device? Otherwise mock location would be the next best thing.

Comment: yes, I am trying that only now since I am not getting proper GPS location in my building.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the device was not able to obtain a proper position fix. Please use DDMS to inject a position to the device, or use a GPS simulator like Mockito from the app store to simulate the device's position. You will need the mock location permission during development, and also to set the GPS mock setting in the developer settings page.

Comment: I have the same problem like yours. What I did is upgrade the SDK to the later versions. 

Try to verify if your location service is enable.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236069/position-indicator-in-here-sdk-premium-is-not-showing